# Charles (or alternative) - re-route request to another URL

Tags: proxy, charles-proxy

I'm using Charles to intercept some traffic and what I would like very much is if I can get Charles to take in a request, but rather than let it continue on its merry way to the original destination URL, have it send all the info to another URL.

So in Charles I will have a rule saying if the URL matches xyz.com/abc?example=[wildcard] then it would re-route that request to abc.com/whatever

I am very unfamiliar with Charles. I've discovered how to do a Map Remote, but I only want to map when a specific rule is met.

Comment: Who is Eric? I'm having issues with this as well, but I see no answer or comment by Eric.

Comment: Eric is a mythical ghost who haunts SO. He's friends with Charles.

Answer (score 0):

In the Edit Mapping dialog for Map Remote Settings, add a Path and Query specification.  In your case, try:

```
Path: /abc
Query: ?example=
```